# Angular Typescript load object from database

Tags: angular, typescript, http, subscription

I have implemented a REST Interface on the backend which is communicating with my frontend node angular server to load data from my MongoDB. On the global class level I am defining an Array which holds all my projects from to the database:

```
protected projects: Array<Project> = [];
```

In my OnInit method I am trying to push all the projects into the array for use:

```
for(let i=0; i <this.user.projects.length; i++) {
      this.databaseService.getDocument('Projects', this.user.projects[i])
        .subscribe((project: Project) => {
          this.projects.push(project);
        });
    }
```

The `databaseService` method looks like this:

```
getDocument(collection: string, documentIdentifier: string): any {
    return this.http.get(`${newLink}${collection}/${documentIdentifier}`)
      .pipe(map((res: Response) => res));
  }
```

Now when I am trying to access an element of the projects array later in `OnInit` I am getting an undefined/ null error:

```
console.log('Projects' , this.projects[0]);
```

Although the project array should be filled correctly. Could it be that the elements in the error are not loaded completely? Because when I am logging the whole array at the same time it gets printed into the console with the message: *Value below was evaluated just now* . Does anybody see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the async call and you might be printing the logs outside of async block. You can try printing the value inside the sync block -

```
for(let i=0; i <this.user.projects.length; i++) {
      this.databaseService.getDocument('Projects', this.user.projects[i])
        .subscribe((project: Project) => {
          this.projects.push(project);
          console.log("Project Added", project);   //<-- This line is added
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a initialize the object inside the for after the getDocument call

```
for(let i=0; i <this.user.projects.length; i++) {
  this.databaseService.getDocument('Projects', this.user.projects[i])
    .subscribe((project: Project) => {
      this.projects[i] = new Project(); //this line add
      this.projects.push(project);
    });
}
```